# MongoDB connections not releasing after query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I made some node app with using MongoDB and Socket.IO, and when I insert some documents, every operation isn't working. And I figured out that MongoDB doesn't insert documents after some documents inserted(I don't know how many exactly). So I checked connections with mongodb shell:

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

before starting node app, it saids:

> { "current" : 1, "available" : 3275, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(639) }

after inserts some docs:

> { "current" : 51, "available" : 3225, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(708) }

turn off node app:

> { "current" : 1, "available" : 3275, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(708) }

This is the code of server side. (I'm using external MongoDB module so it can be little different from Original MongoDB module for node.js. this module is just simple wrapper for MongoDB with Promise based API)

```
const app = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(app);
const am2 = require('am2');
...

am2.connect('localhost', '...', { ... });

const sockets = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    // save the socket into sockets object
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;

    // release socket on disconnection
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        delete sockets[socket.id];
    });

    ...

    // pseudo doc inserting event
    socket.on('/insert/some/docs', (data) => {
        am2.insert({ ... }).then( () => {
            socket.emit('/after/insert/some/docs', {});
        }).catch( ... );
    });
});
```

when client emit '/insert/some/docs' event, server will insert document into MongoDB. first few tries works well, but after some insertion, it does not work anymore.

I think this happen because lot's of connections are still alive after insertion is done, but I don't know why. If it was RDBMS like MySQL, every connection must be close after operation is done, but in MongoDB, it should not be(as I know).

I don't know why this is happening, so it will be very appreciate give me a hand.

Comment: You know the official MongoDB driver [already supports promises](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/ecmascript6/)? Aside from that: connections are only closed explicitly, so just inserting documents doesn't close any connections. It also shouldn't be necessary to do so, because connections are reused. Does the amount of connections grow for each insert?

Comment: So there's something wrong with your am2 package? Got it hosted anywhere like github so we can have a look at the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by releasing cursor after get data from MongoDB. Make sure to release, or it keeps your connection pool and makes your application not working.